# Running Executable

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have an executable that is generated using VC++. The VC++ project includes some of the dlls and when I tried double clicking the exe, it is asking for the path of the dll's.

Is it possible to place the generic dll's into a common folder, open the exe file using the batch file and provide the reference path of the dll's??

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for information on DLL search order on Windows.

Quick and incomplete summary:

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory.
4. The Windows directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

Note: The LIBPATH environment variable is not used.

**EDIT**
To address the comment about having the external DLLs copied locally:

- After adding the files to your project, right-click one, select `Properties`. In the `General` section, change `Item Type` to `Custom Build Tool`. Now in the new section `Custom Build Tool`, change the `Command Line` to copy that particular file to the output directory.
- You can also do all the necessary file copying in the Pre/Post-build steps of the project.

Comment: I think that's not his question.  He is wondering if there is a way to get Visual Studio 2012 to automatically put all the DLLs he needs -- that is, the ones not already on the systemwide search path -- into the target directory, so he can just double-click and run the resulting executable.